# React Native - TextInput.setNativeProps isn't triggering onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to clear a text input using `setNativeProps({ text: '' })` which according to the documentation is a common way to do so -- due to the flickering of state changes -- However, I did notice that `onChange` is not called when `setNativeProps` is called. For me, this is an issue because I am using a resizable TextArea. I need the TextArea to reset its height, which is currently done `onChange`.

If someone can help shed light on my issue it would be much appreciated.

Here is the component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Input extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      height: 35,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { defaultHeight } = this.props;

    if (defaultHeight) {
      this.setState({
        height: defaultHeight,
      });
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (this.state.height !== event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height) {
      this.setState({
        height: Math.max(this.props.defaultHeight, event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height),
      });
    }

    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange(event);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { style, ...props } = this.props;

    return (
      <TextInput
        ref="input"
        style={[{ height:this.state.height }, style]}
        multiline
        {...props}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />);
  }
}

Input.propTypes = {
  style: React.PropTypes.number,
  onChange: React.PropTypes.func,
  defaultHeight: React.PropTypes.number,
};
```

From my other component, I am doing the following to clear the input

`this.refs.input.refs.input.setNativeProps({ text: '' });`

Comment: Are you using a plugin?  If yes, which one?  Can you post your component's code?

Comment: @AdamTerlson i just updated the question to have the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found a way for onChange to still be called, but i did find a solution.

The solution was to create another function that will call setNativeProps and reset the state

```
 resetInputText() {
    this.refs.input.setNativeProps({ text: '' });
    this.setState({
      height: this.props.defaultHeight,
    });
  }
```

From my other component I could then call `this.refs.input.resetInputText();` and see the desired result.